# React-Native-Scrollview's Scroll get Disable when it reached to stickyHeaderIndices

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview

I am trying to make my tab bars sticky I am using `native base` tabs bar and they are using `"react-native-scrollable-tab-view"`. I Wraps my root View with scrollView and sets "stickyHeaderIndices={[1]}" and this works good for making my tab bar sticky on top but when these tab bars are stick on the top scroll is stop working before stick on to the top it is working fine but when these tabs get stick on to the top scroller stops it working any suggestion?

I tried to add another scrollView so my scroll gets work but no luck, I have FlatList component inside the tabs but FlatList's scroll also not working after stickyHeaderIndices before stickyHeaderIndices scroll works.

```
 <ScrollView
      stickyHeaderIndices={[1]}
      ref={ref => this.scrollView = ref}
      onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
        _scrollToBottomY = contentHeight
      }}
      contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1, flex: 1}}>
 >  <AnotherComponent/>
    <MyTabsComponent />
</ScrollView>
```

The scroll should work after the stickyHeaderIndices.

Comment: Did u get any solution buddy

Comment: @ManiKantTiwari i found a work around, I have disabled the nested scrolls and of flatlist list just using a root scroll, May be this helps you.
https://dev.to/netguru/stickyheader-js-beautiful-headers-in-react-native-5ac1